# Limited controls in WPF Form (win32exception conflicts with 10,000 controls per window)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, image-processing, win32-process

I have a program running fine but when it hit nearly 10,000 images in WPF form thrown exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully.

it so weird, sounds poor design, but functioning well as per the requirements. Without splitting process in to multiple, is there any better way that helps in getting rid of this issue and allow users to process over 10,000 images (controls in form).

I have double checked unmanged code disposed properly and used using blocks etc..

Background : Application creates image thumbnails of PDF pages and the images are stored in cache. Application is working well in handling a big load in giga bytes though it takes fair bit of time to create images on screen .(this is an acceptable delay)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have reached the [Windows limit of 10,000 user handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326591).

You might want to try batching up the processing, or maybe using a virtualizing panel like the [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) to display the images. This will only create UI controls as they are scrolled into view.

Comment: Processing them in batch implementation takes time, this program is running fine for all other cases. Virtualizing the panel I have to see, I need to think here as the application is producing the images out from pdf and dispalying all code is in backend and dynamic. All images are within the wrap panel, inside stackpanel ,inside checkbox and image control.

Comment: WrapPanel is not virtualizing, so that's probably what's causing your performance problem. Try replacing it with a virtualizing WrapPanel, such as this open source one: http://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/ or this licensed one: http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/WPF_SL/virtualizingwrappanel_wpf_sl.htm.

Comment: I will try with virtualizing controls and update here..Might take little bit extra time for this.